# HttpClient copy data from Request.Form .NET Core

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, dotnet-httpclient

I have POST query with Form data with files and I need to send the same data to another POST request.
I'm going to use for this HttpClient class.

Is there a way to copy all `Request.Form` data and insert them to new request? Or I need to add every param?

I mean something like this:

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var httpResponseMessage = await httpClient.PostAsync("some_url", Request.Form);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to copy all Request.Form data and insert them to new request? Or I need to add every param?

You need to add every param like below:

Model in ProjectA:

```
public class FormData
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public IFormFile File { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

View in ProjectA:

```
@model FormData
<form asp-action="Post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div>
        Id:<input asp-for="Id"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        Name:<input asp-for="Name"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        FIle:<input asp-for="File" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="create" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Controller in ProjectA:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post(FormData formData)
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    // var formData = HttpContext.Request.Form;
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:63331");//your applicationUrl
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();

    var multiContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();

    var file = formData.File;
    if (file != null)
    {
        var fileStreamContent = new StreamContent(file.OpenReadStream());
        multiContent.Add(fileStreamContent, "File", file.FileName);
    }

    multiContent.Add(new StringContent(formData.Id.ToString()), "id");
    multiContent.Add(new StringContent(formData.Name.ToString()), "name");


    var response = await client.PostAsync("/api/values", multiContent);
    //do your stuff...
    return Ok();
}
```

Model in ProjectB:

```
public class FormDataModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public IFormFile File { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Controller in ProjectB:

```
[HttpPost]
public void Post([FromForm]FormDataModel model)
{
      //...
}
```

Result:
[image]